# PHP file upload/move doesn't work

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to move/copy/upload an image from tmp directory to another directory using following code, but I don't see my image being moved/copied to the destination. Is there any alternative?

```
    public function uploadToS3($file, $tmp_url) {
    if (strrpos($file, '.tmp') == strlen($file)-4) {
                $file = substr($file, 0, strlen($file)-4);
            }
        $destination = "var/www/html/image" . $file;

    if (file_exists($destination)) {
        echo 'File '. $destination. ' already exists!';
    } else {
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_url, $destination);
    }
}
    //Ex: $tmp_url = http://localhost/mage/media/tmp/catalog/product/s/c/abc.png
    //Ex: $destination = /var/www/html/image/s/c/abc.png
```

Following comments below I've tried following php code which fails too

```
 <?php
$tmp_url = "var/www/html/abc/abc.png";
$destination = "var/www/html/des/abc.png";
 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_url, $destination)){echo "success";}else{echo "fail";}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the starting / in $destination = "var/www/html/image" . $file;

Comment: do if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_url, $destination)){echo "success";}else{echo "fail";} and post the output...done

Comment: @WilliamMadede: it says fail.

Comment: How you call your function `uploadToS3`??

Comment: Update
$destination = "var/www/html/image" . $file;
to
$destination = "var/www/html/image/" . $file;

Comment: @WilliamMadede: Same error. Even destination directory is having 777 permission. Actually my destination url is like var/www/html/image/s/c/abc.png

Comment: try $destination = "/var/www/html/image/" . $file ??

Comment: @MuratCemYALIN: sorry that doesn't work either. Please check updated code.

Comment: php manual says: This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

Comment: I tried `copy($tmp_url, $destination)` which is copying file to destination folder.

Comment: `$tmp_url = "var/www/html/abc/abc.png";` when using a full system path, the syntax is `$tmp_url = "/var/www/html/abc/abc.png";` with a leading slash and the same for the other one, or use a relative path as in `../folder/file.xxx`. Use error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Also please check the destination image folder has `777 / 775 permission`

```
$ImageName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileElementName = 'file';
$path = 'var/www/html/image/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['file']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location);
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to uploading files it's always a good idea to construct the destination in a full path manner - why not create a global helper that gives you access to your base path:

```
/**
 * Return the base path.
 *
 * @param void
 * @return string
 */
function base_path()
{
    // I go back 2 directories here - it all depends where
    // you decide to place this global helper function.
    return realpath(__DIR__ . '/../..');
}
```

Great, now this is available globally, you may decide to use it like so:

```
$destination = base_path() . '/var/www/html/image';
```

This way, you don't have to worry about your current location - it's just too easy.